# Emacs CEDET for OpenCV C++ Interface

Tags: emacs, opencv, cedet

So, I have used CEDET for awhile now, and things work pretty well in general.
I'm moving from using it with C to C++, specifically for OpenCV 2.3 (linux) and I'm running into problems.  I'm using emacs24 with the latest dev version of CEDET.

It is unable to parse some symbols and their members, like: `KeyPoint, Mat,` etc.

Many of the function symbols ARE parsed however, such as `line(), imshow(), imread()`, etc.

I'm looking for help on how to debug what's wrong with my setup, or someone who has successfully setup opencv c++ api.

Here is my relevant cedet config:

```
;; brian-cedet.el
;; Contains my personal configuration for CEDET

;; Loads for CEDET 
(load-file "/home/terranpro/code/cedet/common/cedet.el")

(add-to-list 'Info-default-directory-list
             (expand-file-name "~/code/cedet/common"))
(add-to-list 'Info-directory-list
             (expand-file-name "~/code/cedet/common"))

(add-to-list 'Info-directory-list
             (expand-file-name "~/code/cedet/semantic/doc"))
(add-to-list 'Info-directory-list
             (expand-file-name "~/code/cedet/eieio"))
(add-to-list 'Info-directory-list
             (expand-file-name "~/code/cedet/speedbar"))
(add-to-list 'Info-directory-list
             (expand-file-name "~/code/cedet/cogre"))
(add-to-list 'Info-directory-list
             (expand-file-name "~/code/cedet/ede"))
(add-to-list 'Info-directory-list
             (expand-file-name "~/code/cedet/srecode"))

(require 'ede)

(global-ede-mode t)

;;(semantic-load-enable-minimum-features)
(semantic-load-enable-code-helpers)
;;(semantic-load-enable-gaudy-code-helpers)
(semantic-load-enable-excessive-code-helpers)
;;(semantic-load-enable-semantic-debugging-helpers)

(require 'semantic-ia)

(require 'semantic-gcc)

(require 'semantic-sb)

(require 'semanticdb)
(global-semanticdb-minor-mode 1)

(require 'semanticdb-global)
(semanticdb-enable-gnu-global-databases 'c-mode)
(semanticdb-enable-gnu-global-databases 'c++-mode)

(require 'semantic-c)

(setq semantic-load-turn-useful-things-on t)

(semantic-add-system-include "/usr/include/glib-2.0" 'c-mode)
(semantic-add-system-include "/usr/include/glib-2.0" 'c++-mode)
(semantic-add-system-include "/usr/include/gtk-3.0" 'c-mode)
(semantic-add-system-include "/usr/include/gtk-3.0" 'c++-mode)

(semantic-add-system-include "/usr/local/include/" 'c-mode)
(semantic-add-system-include "/usr/local/include/" 'c++-mode)

(semantic-add-system-include "/usr/local/include/opencv" 'c-mode)
(semantic-add-system-include "/usr/local/include/opencv2" 'c++-mode)
(semantic-add-system-include "/usr/local/include/opencv" 'c-mode)
(semantic-add-system-include "/usr/local/include/opencv2" 'c++-mode)

(add-to-list 'semantic-lex-c-preprocessor-symbol-file 
         '"/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/types_c.h")
(add-to-list 'semantic-lex-c-preprocessor-symbol-file 
         '"/usr/local/include/opencv2/imgproc/types_c.h")

(add-to-list 'semantic-lex-c-preprocessor-symbol-map '("CV_PROP_RW" . ""))
(add-to-list 'semantic-lex-c-preprocessor-symbol-map '("CV_EXPORTS" . ""))
(add-to-list 'semantic-lex-c-preprocessor-symbol-map '("CV_EXPORTS_W_SIMPLE" . ""))

(defun my-cedet-hook ()
  (local-set-key [(control return)] 'semantic-ia-complete-symbol)
  (local-set-key "\C-c?" 'semantic-ia-complete-symbol-menu)
  (local-set-key "\C-c>" 'semantic-complete-analyze-inline)
  (local-set-key "\C-c=" 'semantic-decoration-include-visit)
  (local-set-key "\C-cj" 'semantic-ia-fast-jump)
  (local-set-key "\C-cq" 'semantic-ia-show-doc)
  (local-set-key "\C-cs" 'semantic-ia-show-summary)
  (local-set-key "\C-cp" 'semantic-analyze-proto-impl-toggle)
  (local-set-key "\C-c+" 'semantic-tag-folding-show-block)
  (local-set-key "\C-c-" 'semantic-tag-folding-fold-block)
  (local-set-key "\C-c\C-c+" 'semantic-tag-folding-show-all)
  (local-set-key "\C-c\C-c-" 'semantic-tag-folding-fold-all))
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'my-cedet-hook)
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'my-cedet-hook)
(add-hook 'lisp-interaction-mode-hook 'my-cedet-hook)

(global-semantic-tag-folding-mode 1)
```

Comment: Could you provide example, how you include headers, etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a working configuration now; thanks to Alex Ott and David Engster from cedet-devel mailing list.  To note their corrections, there were some lines in my configuration that were ' not needed and possibly hurtful.'  After updating the config, **deleting all files in ~/.semanticdb** and restarting emacs, things are working as expected!

I've also included a sample cpp file for testing the configuration.  Thanks guys!

```
(load-file "/home/terranpro/code/cedet/common/cedet.el")

(require 'ede)

(global-ede-mode t)

;;(semantic-load-enable-minimum-features)
(semantic-load-enable-code-helpers)
;;(semantic-load-enable-gaudy-code-helpers)
(semantic-load-enable-excessive-code-helpers)
;;(semantic-load-enable-semantic-debugging-helpers)

;; CEDET-devel mailing list said these werent needed
;; and possibly hurtful
;;(require 'semantic-ia)

;;(require 'semantic-gcc)

;;(require 'semantic-sb)

;;(require 'semanticdb)
;;(global-semanticdb-minor-mode 1)

;;(require 'semanticdb-global)

(semanticdb-enable-gnu-global-databases 'c-mode)
(semanticdb-enable-gnu-global-databases 'c++-mode)

(require 'semantic-c)

(setq semantic-load-turn-useful-things-on t)

(semantic-add-system-include "/usr/local/include/" 'c-mode)
(semantic-add-system-include "/usr/local/include/" 'c++-mode)

(add-to-list 'semantic-lex-c-preprocessor-symbol-file 
         '"/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/types_c.h")
(add-to-list 'semantic-lex-c-preprocessor-symbol-file 
         '"/usr/local/include/opencv2/imgproc/types_c.h")

(add-to-list 'semantic-lex-c-preprocessor-symbol-map '("CV_PROP_RW" . ""))
(add-to-list 'semantic-lex-c-preprocessor-symbol-map '("CV_EXPORTS" . ""))
(add-to-list 'semantic-lex-c-preprocessor-symbol-map '("CV_EXPORTS_W_SIMPLE" . ""))
(add-to-list 'semantic-lex-c-preprocessor-symbol-map '("CV_EXPORTS_W" . ""))
(add-to-list 'semantic-lex-c-preprocessor-symbol-map '("CV_EXPORTS_W_MAP" . ""))
(add-to-list 'semantic-lex-c-preprocessor-symbol-map '("CV_INLINE" . ""))

(defun my-cedet-hook ()
  (local-set-key [(control return)] 'semantic-ia-complete-symbol)
  (local-set-key "\C-c?" 'semantic-ia-complete-symbol-menu)
  (local-set-key "\C-c>" 'semantic-complete-analyze-inline)
  (local-set-key "\C-c=" 'semantic-decoration-include-visit)
  (local-set-key "\C-cj" 'semantic-ia-fast-jump)
  (local-set-key "\C-cq" 'semantic-ia-show-doc)
  (local-set-key "\C-cs" 'semantic-ia-show-summary)
  (local-set-key "\C-cp" 'semantic-analyze-proto-impl-toggle)
  (local-set-key "\C-c+" 'semantic-tag-folding-show-block)
  (local-set-key "\C-c-" 'semantic-tag-folding-fold-block)
  (local-set-key "\C-c\C-c+" 'semantic-tag-folding-show-all)
  (local-set-key "\C-c\C-c-" 'semantic-tag-folding-fold-all))
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'my-cedet-hook)
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'my-cedet-hook)
(add-hook 'lisp-interaction-mode-hook 'my-cedet-hook)

(global-semantic-tag-folding-mode 1)
```

And the CPP test file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  KeyPoint k;
  Mat m;

  // m should have members like m.clone()
  // k has members like k.pt (Point2f pt)

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like, the Semantic parser couldn't parse class declaration - it sees it as `CV_EXPORTS Mat` not as `Mat` itself, although `CV_EXPORTS` should be expanded into empty string. I've used following configuration and it worked fine for C code, but not for C++.  I suggest that you write to cedet-devel mailing list with examples - just write there, and if necessary, I'll provide more comments for your mail...

```
(ede-cpp-root-project "OpenCV/C++ test"
     :name "OpenCV/C++ test"
     :file "/Users/ott/development/opencv-examples/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
     :include-path '("/"
                  )
     :system-include-path '("/opt/local/include"
                     "/opt/local/include/opencv"
                     "/opt/local/include/opencv2")
     :spp-table '(
                  ("CV_PROP_RW" . "")
                  ("CV_EXPORTS" . "")
                  ("CV_EXPORTS_W_SIMPLE" . "")
               ("CV_EXPORTS_W" . "")
               ("CV_EXPORTS_W_MAP" . "")
               ("CV_INLINE" . ""))
     :local-variables (list
               (cons 'semantic-lex-c-preprocessor-symbol-file
                 (cons "/opt/local/include/opencv2/core/types_c.h"
                   (cons "/opt/local/include/opencv2/imgproc/types_c.h"
                     semantic-lex-c-preprocessor-symbol-file)))))
```

Comment: Thanks Alex!  I have contacted the cedet-devel list, and am eagerly awaiting assistance.  I will update this question if/when a solution is available.